# Magento 2 : Add to cart product with custom option programmatically

Tags: magento2, custom-options, addtocart

I want to add to cart product with custom options. I added simple product, but can't able to add with custom options.

How to do it ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code in your controller. It's for specific product. If you want to add multiple products. Then, you need to save multiple product collection in **$product** variable.

```
protected $formKey;
protected $_productFactory;
protected $_cart;
protected $messageManager;
protected $_url;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $managerInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->messageManager = $managerInterface;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
}

public function execute()
{
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productID);
    if ($product) {
        foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
            $custom_option_value = '';
            if (isset($value['super_attribute']) || !empty($value['super_attribute'])) {
                $custom_option_value = $value['super_attribute'];
            }
            $this->addCartProduct($value['id'], $value['qty'], $custom_option_value,$product);
        }
        $this->_cart->save();
    }
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Shopping cart updated succesfully.');
}

public function addCartProduct($productID, $productQty, $custom_option_val,$product)
{
    $info = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $productID,
            'qty' => $productQty,
            'super_attribute' => $custom_option_val
        ]
    );
    return $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $info);
}
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: How can I do the same in .phtml file?

Answer (score 1):

[add products to cart with customizable options](https://takeoff.digital/case-studies/magento-2-add-products-to-cart-with-custom-options/)

```
$product = $productFactory->create();
$product->setStoreId(1)->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));
$params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$params->setQty($qty);
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
if ($value["sku"] == 'RED') { //add this if to search for your custom option by sku or the value name etc.
$options[$value['option_id']] = $value['option_type_ id'];
$params->setOptions($options); //set the customizable option to the product

}
}
}
try {
$quote1->addProduct($product, $params); //add to cart 
} catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```